# Show UserControls In "ItemsControl" with custom option in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, scrollviewer, winrt-xaml

I have a `ItemsControl` in `ScrollViewer` and I set `ItemsPanel` of my `ItemsControl` to Horizontal `StackPanel` and i bound it to `ObservableCollection` of `userControls`.Now I wanna when user click on icons of open `UserControls` in my `ItemsControl`,automatically `scrollviwer`'s offset change to show icon clicked `UserControl`.( I have a Icon for my each `usercontrols`)

And also when user open new `UserControl` ,I wanna my `ItemsControl` automatically show it ( now when I open a new `usercontrol` i should scroll my `ItemControl` to reach it),
can I do this with above controls ,if yes, can you tell me how? If not, I appreciate to tell me which controls should I use controls and how?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'opening' a user control? It may help to have code and screenshots/mockups to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean that add a UserControl to ObservableCollection and then ItemControl Show it.

Comment: Don't use FrameworkElement descendants in the model layer, it's a very bad coding practice